# What does Quine mean by $\;\hat{a}\phi=\;$V?

Tags: logic, set-theory, philosophy, lambda-calculus

This is some kind of weird notation. I know how $\;\hat{a}\;$ was used in the Principia Mathematica (as an equivalent of $\;\eta$-reduction in lambda calculus), but what does it do here $\;\hat{a}(a=a.\phi)\;$?

Why is $\;\hat{a}\phi\;$ equivalent to a universal set, and why does a $\;\Lambda\;$ mean an empty set (if V [states for the universal set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations#Admissibility_of_useful_large_sets) and according to Quine's "... is either V or $\Lambda$") ?

[Fragment of W.V.O.Quine's "Reference and Modality"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNseC.jpg)

Comment: Please have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and re-fromat you question accordingly.

Comment: See also [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327706/who-first-discovered-the-concept-corresponding-to-the-symbol-of-class-comprehens)

Answer (score 1):

See [The Notation in *Principia Mathematica*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pm-notation/#Clas).

Let $\phi$ a statement that is either True or False.

$\hat {\alpha}(\alpha = \alpha)$ is simply $\{ \alpha \mid \alpha = \alpha \}$, i.e. the class such that ...

But $\alpha=\alpha$ is always true; thus, $\{ \alpha \mid \alpha = \alpha \} = \text V$, i.e. the "universe".

Now, the formule $(\alpha = \alpha) \land \phi$ has the truth value of $\phi$, and thus $\{ \alpha \mid \alpha = \alpha \land \phi \}$ is equal to $\text V$ or $\emptyset$ ($\Lambda$) according to the truth value of $\phi$.